# Constant Riemannian Metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M=\mathbb R^n$ and define for each $x\in \mathbb R^n$, define 
$$\langle v,w\rangle_x= \langle v,w\rangle_0$$
where $v,w\in T_x\mathbb R^n\equiv \mathbb R^n\equiv T_0\mathbb R^n$. Hence we see that $M=\mathbb R^n$, admits constant metrics.

Is there any other manifold (other than $\mathbb R^n$) which admits constant metrics...

One guess may be Lie group admit constant metric. Is there any other example.

Comment: LaTeX tip: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for angle brackets. `<` and `>` are relation symbols; they are not only different, the spacing is different too.

Comment: I'm perhaps a little confused as to what this should mean in general. You got "lucky" here because you can canonically identify the tangent spaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with each other as just $\mathbb{R}^n$ making the idea of a "constant metric" sensible. In general though I feel like you need to make identifications first. If you are on a Lie group there is a canonical way to do this via the pushforward of $L_g$ identifying $T_1G$ with $T_gG$, but besides that case the question doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting your "admits constant metrics" in the following way: Any point $p\in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ with local coordinates $(u_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ such that in terms of the $u_i$ the metric tensor $g_{ik}$ is constant. This means that any point $p$ has a neighborhood $U$ which is isometric to a euclidean $n$-ball.

Examples of such manifolds can be produced in the following way: In $\Bbb R^n$, provided with the standard euclidean metric, take $r$ linearly independent vectors $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_r$ and call two points $x$, $y\in\Bbb R^n$ *equivalent* if
$$y-x=\sum_{k=1}^r j_k \>a_k,\qquad j_k\in{\mathbb Z}\quad (1\leq k\leq r)\ .$$
It's easy to check that $M:=\Bbb R^n{/}\!\sim\ $ has the desired property. When $r=n$ then $M$ is compact and is called an $n$-dimensional *flat torus*.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that with the technical assumption of completeness, *all* examples which "admit constant metrics" arise in the way you described, possibly with different notion of "equivalent".

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting the question differently:  Namely, when can I use precisely what you did to define a metric?

The issue is that you can't always make a well defined identification of the tangent space at one point with the tangent space at another.  So, saying $v\in T_p M$ "corresponds" to $v'\in T_q M$ doesn't always make sense.

For example, on $S^2$, given a nonzero tangent vector at the north pole, it should be clear that if this "corresponds" to anything, it should "correspond" to something nonzero.  Then, a "correspondance" to every point on $S^2$ is nothing but a vector field on $S^2$ which vanishes nowhere.  Unfortunately, the [Hairy Ball Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) states that there is no such vector field.

The class of manifolds you are looking for are the so called [Parallelizable Manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable).  These are precisely those manifolds for which the tangent bundle admits a global trivialization.  After choosing such a trivialization, choosing any basis for the tangent space at some particular point.  Then, via the trivialaztion, this defines a basis at each point of your manifold and this gives you a way of identifying tangent spaces at different points.

I want to stress that this is very *noncanonical* - you must choose a trivialization *and* a basis.  Different choices will give rise to different Riemannian metrics with different properties.

Parallizable manifolds include $\mathbb{R}^n$ and all Lie groups, as you guessed, but also contain *many* more manifolds.  For example, $S^7$ is not a Lie group, but is parallelizable.  Further, the product of any sphere with an odd dimensional sphere is parallelizable.